# accessing Active Directory current time though python ldap

Tags: python-ldap

Is there a way to fetch current time on a remote Active Directory controller using python-ldap module?
My end goal is to determine if an account is expired or not. I have to do this remotely, using python and the ldap module.

I am using http://www.python-ldap.org/ to connect to a AD on WIn2003

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for this question, thanks to this article:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q219005

so a query like this would get you the results

l.search_ext_s("", ldap.SCOPE_BASE, user_filter)

where user_filter='(&(objectClass=*))'

You can find 'currentTime' in the results.

Update:
If you're on openldap and you don't see 'currentTime' in the results, then make sure that [ldap monitoring](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/monitoringslapd.html) is enabled.

Comment: user_filter is just a name. not well named though,as this filter is not filtering for just users

Comment: Suffers from link rot